# How to import dates correctly from this .csv file into Matlab?

Tags: matlab, csv, import

I have a .csv file with the first column containing dates, a snippet of which looks like the following:

```
date,values
03/11/2020,1
03/12/2020,2
3/14/20,3
3/15/20,4
3/16/20,5
04/01/2020,6
```

I would like to import this data into Matlab (I think the best way would probably be using the `readtable()` function, [see here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/readtable.html)). My goal is to bring the dates into Matlab as a [datetime array](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datetime.html). As you can see above, the problem is that the dates in the original .csv file are not consistently formatted. Some of them are in the format `mm/dd/yyyy` and some of them are `mm/dd/yy`.

Simply calling `data = readtable('myfile.csv')` on the .csv file results in the following, which is not correct:

```
'03/11/2020'    1
'03/12/2020'    2
'03/14/0020'    3
'03/15/0020'    4
'03/16/0020'    5
'04/01/2020'    6
```

Does anyone know a way to automatically account for this type of data in the import?

Thank you!

*My version: Matlab R2017a*

**EDIT ---------------------------------------**

Following the suggestion of Max, I have tried specifiying some of the input options for the read command using the following:

```
T = readtable('example.csv',...
              'Format','%{dd/MM/yyyy}D %d',...
              'Delimiter', ',',...
              'HeaderLines', 0,...
              'ReadVariableNames', true)
```

which results in:

```
    date       values
    __________    ______

    03/11/2020    1     
    03/12/2020    2     
    NaT           3     
    NaT           4     
    NaT           5     
    04/01/2020    6
```

and you can see that this is not working either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are sure all the dates involved do not go back more than 100 years, you can easily apply the pivot method which was in use in the last century (before th 2K bug warned the world of the danger of the method).

They used to code dates in 2 digits only, knowing that `87` actually meant `1987`. A user (or a computer) would add the missing years automatically.

In your case, you can read the full table, parse the dates, then it is easy to detect which dates are inconsistent. Identify them, correct them, and you are good to go.

With your example:

```
a = readtable(tfile) ;                  % read the file
dates = datetime(a.date) ;              % extract first column and convert to [datetime]
idx2change = dates.Year < 2000 ;        % Find which dates where on short format
dates.Year(idx2change) = dates.Year(idx2change) + 2000 ; % Correct truncated years
a.date = dates                          % reinject corrected [datetime] array into the table
```

yields:

```
a = 
       date        values
    ___________    ______
    11-Mar-2020    1     
    12-Mar-2020    2     
    14-Mar-2020    3     
    15-Mar-2020    4     
    16-Mar-2020    5     
    01-Apr-2020    6
```

Comment: Okay, nice simple solution. I will accept it! +1 for the background. Out of interest, you don't know if there is an automatic detection option during the import itself by any chance?

Comment: I doubt there is an option you could simply set in the `readtable` parameters which could take care of that for you. But even for me, I don't use the high level importing functions and write my own parsers, and I face the same problem than you pretty often. Even in my parsers I try to read as much as I can in one go, and do the corrections at a later stage. It's usually so much faster than having to check/validate line by line.

Comment: I will try to follow your advice in future, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of specifying the format explicitly (as I also suggested before), one should use the `delimiterImportoptions` and in the case of a csv-file, use the `delimitedTextImportOptions`

```
opts = delimitedTextImportOptions('NumVariables',2,...% how many variables per row?
'VariableNamesLine',1,... % is there a header? If yes, in which line are the variable names?
'DataLines',2,... % in which line does the actual data starts?
'VariableTypes',{'datetime','double'})% as what data types should the variables be read

readtable('myfile.csv',opts)
```

because the neat little feature recognizes the format of the `datetime` automatically, as it knows that it must be a `datetime`-object =)